# Arabic Typesetting with texmaker editor and pdfLatex

Tags: fonts, texmaker, arabic

I'm writing a book in French, but i need to write a chapter in Arabic. To do so I've used the arabtex.

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
```

after the preamble I've done this

```
\chapter*{\<السلام عليكم>}
```

After compiling my code i get this :

`! Illegal arabic command: ?.\a@cmderr ...age {Illegal arabic command: \nxp #1}\a@@cmd = {{\a@puttt #1\ar... \chapter{\<?????? ?????>}`

But when ii change the arabic letter with the \<> tag

```
\chapter*{\<this is an arabic message>}
```

I got :
[image]

which is kind of random and insignificant, so how can I write in arabic in my texmaker editor and compile my code properly ?

EDIT : This is a full Example :

```
  \documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}
    \usepackage{arabtex}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{ae}
    \usepackage{aecompl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{\<سلام>}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Did you think of using `XeLaTeX`, `arabxetex` and `polyglossia`?

Comment: Please complete your code to provide a small, compilable document demonstrating the issue. This allows people to understand your situation and reproduce the problem - prerequisites for offering you much by way of useful advice!

Comment: @cfr : A full example has been Added.. Thank you

Comment: You've specified `latin1` as your input encoding (twice) but the characters you've typed are not in latin1. If you want to input Arabic characters directly, you want to be using unicode. XeLaTeX is one option but you can use (pdf)LaTeX with `arabtex` as described on page 34 of the user manual. You need the `utf8` option for `inputenc` and `\setcode{utf8}` and make sure that the file really is saved in UTF-8 encoding. Then you can switch to Arabic language and `arabtex` should expect UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: @cfr I've changed the inputenc to utf8 and i did the setcode{utf8}, But i'm still having the same problem "! Illegal arabic command: ?. " and after saving the file and re-opening it, i realise that the letters are turning into question marks ... Thanks for the effort

Comment: Actually, I guess you need to change the `inputenc` option for the rest. For Arabic, you need to load the `utf8` package it seems. I misread the instructions. See my answer below for the modifications I made to your example to produce the output shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation. Page 34 of the manual explains how to use UTF-8 encoding. Applying the instructions to your example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
  \setarab
  \chapter{\<سلام>}
\end{document}
```

[image: Chapter title]

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not necessary but you cannot save your file in two input encodings so you need either `utf8` or `latin1`. Hence, you'll need to change the option for `inputenc` as shown since you want to use UTF-8 for Arabic.

Note that this code is using obsolete commands. (Something is still using pre-LaTeX2e font switches, for example.) Also, you should consider switching from `ae` and using `cm-super` or `lmodern` fonts which include the characters and don't need the emulation.

When saving the file, you have to ensure that it is saving in the correct encoding. If you were using `latin1`, try saving a new version and double-check the encoding your editor is using. Otherwise you will find characters becoming question marks.